# Is there any way to choose the value-labels on the x-axis in ggplot without changing your data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data frame:

```
Techs <-
  data.frame(
    Patent_number = c(403, 410, 500, 600, 601, 770),
    techcategory = c(16, 18, rep(16, 4))
  )

# Techs
#
#   Patent_number techcategory
# 1           403           16
# 2           410           18
# 3           500           16
# 4           600           16
# 5           601           16
# 6           770           16
```

My code for ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=Techs, aes(Techs$techcategory, fill = factor(techcategory))) + geom_bar() +
  ylab("Number of patents") +
  xlab("Category") +
  ggtitle("Random title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

I'm trying to create a bar plot based on the techcategory column in my data. However the labels used in that column are numerical values like 16 and 18. I would like to replace these numbers in my ggplot with words instead. I also don't want them to be reorganized. Whatever word I replace "1" with should still be the first column to the left, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use a **named vector** of labels. I see that in your data `techcategory` is a factor with 35 levels - so you should create a static vector instead of creating it in the `scale_` functions as I have done. Then you just use `labels = <static vector>` in the scales.

```
ggplot(data=Techs, aes(techcategory, fill = techcategory)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete("techcategory",
                   labels = c(
                     "18" = "Company1",
                     "16" = "Company2"
                   )) +
  scale_fill_discrete("techcategory",
                   labels = c(
                     "18" = "Company1",
                     "16" = "Company2"
                   ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate column with names you're after

```
Techs$words <- ifelse(Techs$techcategory == 16, "1", "2")
```

Then use that for plotting:

```
ggplot(data=Techs, aes(Techs$words, fill = factor(words))) + geom_bar() +
   ylab("Number of patents") +
   xlab("Category") +
   ggtitle("Random title") +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
   guides(fill=FALSE)
```